# How to chech type in python elegantly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I accept some variables encoded in JSON from the frontend noted as `var`. then how can I check if the var is structured like `List[str]` or `Dict[str,str]` without using something like `for i in var:`

Comment: Your problem description is a bit unclear to me, but if what you're trying to do is make sure that every item in a sequence conforms to a type requirement, then you will have to eventually iterate over every single item with one way or another. No need for fancy tricks.

Comment: Simply put, in the general case you can't. Python container types do not restrict - and thus not express - their item type.